# Does the shape of the pipe (the length not the cross section area) affect resistive force?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, drag, viscosity, bernoulli-equation

Does the shape of the pipe (the length not the cross section area) affect resistive force acting on water? Does keeping the pipe straight or keeping it in curves folded over each other effect the efficiency of water transport?

Comment: What does "keeping it in curves folded over each other" mean?

Comment: Like a spring if you stretch a spring hard enough it elongates and becomes straight like my pipe in question but the shape of the spring is curved over each other like a toroid which has its curves folded over itself